# Android - TextView.setText string with \n problem

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, newline

I have a method which retrieves some text from a Firebase:

```
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Contact").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    String textt = (document.getString("Text"));
                    settext(textt);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

When I retrieve the String "Text" I call the method settext:

```
private void settext(String textt){
    mainTextView.setText(textt);
}
```

Here is the value of the string text: "azerty123\nqwerty\ntest"
But the mainTextView prints "azerty123\nqwerty\ntest" without newlines.

Can someone help me?

It's FIXED, just override the method settext to:

```
private void settext(String textt){
    String text = textt.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
    mainTextView.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside `onComplete()`:

```
String textt = document.getString("Text").replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

or

```
String textt = document.getString("Text").replace("\\n", "\n");
```

just in case the string coming from the db contains special characters.

Comment: If u find an answer to my old post, i take it ;)

Comment: Sure, but it's not reproducable and very strange.

Comment: I agree with that